# django - custom_user : How to make and EditProfile view?

Tags: django, django-views, django-validation

I've installed django-registration-redux and custom_user. I have a UserProfile model with fullname,dob and photo as extra fields.

I have connected the UserProfile with user-registration so as to save the additional fields to UserProfile table.

Here my questions are...

1. How do I validate fields in UserProfile model at the time of registration so that I can prevent addition of a user to the emailuser table. Say, if the dob given is invalid or not in allowed range, then stop adding a user to emailuser table.
2. How can I make an EditProfile system that allows authenticated users to edit their profile (/user/edit - id to be obtained from session).

Below is my **settings.py** file

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'custom_user',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    #------------
    'registration',
    'userprofile',    
]

AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'custom_user.EmailUser'
```

---

**models.py**

```
class UserProfile(models.Model):
    user=models.OneToOneField(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE,
        primary_key=True,)
    fullname=models.CharField(max_length=70, blank=False)
    dob=models.DateField(blank=False)
    photo=models.ImageField(upload_to='profile_images', blank=False)
    def __str__(self):
        return self.user.email   


def user_registered_callback(sender, user, request, **kwargs):
    profile = UserProfile(user = user)
    profile.fullname =request.POST["fullname"]
    profile.dob ="%s-%s-%s" % (request.POST["dob_year"],request.POST["dob_month"],request.POST["dob_day"])
    if 'photo' in request.FILES:
        profile.photo = request.FILES['photo']

    profile.save()

user_registered.connect(user_registered_callback)
```

---

**forms.py**

```
class UserProfileForm(RegistrationForm):
    fullname=forms.CharField(required=True,label="Full name",  min_length=3, max_length=75)
    dob=forms.DateField(required=True,label="Date of birth", 
        widget=forms.SelectDateWidget(years=range(now.year-settings.AGE_UPPER,now.year-settings.AGE_LOWER)))
    photo=forms.ImageField(required=False)
```

**views.py**

```
def profile(request):
    if not request.user.is_authenticated():
        return HttpResponseRedirect('/user/login')
    else:
         return render(request, 'userprofile/profile.html', {"user":request.user})

class EditProfile(UpdateView):
    template_name = 'userprofile/edit_profile.html'

    fields = ['fullname','dob','photo']
```

---

main **urls.py**

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
    url(r'user/register/$', 
        RegistrationView.as_view(form_class = UserProfileForm), 
        name = 'registration_register'),

    url(r'^user/', include('registration.backends.default.urls')),
    url(r'^user/', include('userprofile.urls')),
```

---

**userprofile.urls.py**

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^profile/$', views.profile, name='profile'),
    url(r'^profile/edit/$', views.EditProfile.as_view(), name='edit_profile'),
 ]
```

---

Right now I'm, getting *EditProfile is missing a QuerySet. Define EditProfile.model, EditProfile.queryset, or override EditProfile.get_queryset().*

Is it the right way to proceed? Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks